# Showing full (unabbreviated) Python output in Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, python

The result of a certain Python (statsmodel module) code in org-mode is abbreviated:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
  import pandas as pd
  import statsmodels.api as sm

  auto_df=pd.read_csv('Auto.csv', usecols= ['mpg', 'horsepower'], na_values= ['?']) 

  auto_df['horsepower'] = pd.to_numeric(auto_df['horsepower'])

  auto_df.dropna(inplace=True)

  X = auto_df['horsepower']
  X = sm.add_constant(X)

  olsmod = sm.OLS(auto_df['mpg'], X)
  olsres = olsmod.fit()
  pred = olsres.get_prediction([1,98])
  return(pred.summary_frame())
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: mean   mean_se  ...  obs_ci_lower  obs_ci_upper
: 0  24.467077  0.251262  ...     14.809396     34.124758
: 
: [1 rows x 6 columns]
```

I'm referring to the ellipses in the table below `#+Results`.

How can I see the full results table?

A comment suggested this could be a a pandas issue, but I don't think so since the output is from a statsmodels function.

And I don't think it's because of statsmodels because here, the full is `pred.summary_frame()` results table is shown:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
  import pandas as pd
  import statsmodels.api as sm
  import numpy as np

  nsample = 50
  sig = 0.25
  X = np.linspace(0, 20, nsample)
  X = sm.add_constant(X)
  beta = [5., 0.5]
  y_true = np.dot(X, beta)
  y = y_true + sig * np.random.normal(size=nsample)

  olsmod = sm.OLS(y, X)
  olsres = olsmod.fit()

  pred = olsres.get_prediction([1,17])

  return(pred.summary_frame())
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: mean  mean_se  mean_ci_lower  mean_ci_upper  obs_ci_lower  obs_ci_upper
: 0  13.559089   0.0522      13.454134      13.664043     13.069874     14.048303
```

One more note, the abbreviate one, from my first example, shows fully in the python shell.

Comment: Please show the complete source block (and show it in text: Org mode prides itself as being your life in *plain text*  - images are a poor substitute). If you are using pandas, then that's where you should concentrate: Org mode probably has nothing to do with it. See e.g.[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351968/how-to-display-full-non-truncated-dataframe-information-in-html-when-convertin)

Comment: Thanks @NickD. I updated the question. As I mentioned, since the output in the shell is complete I don't think it's related to a pandas or, more likely, statsmodels option. Agreed?

Comment: The other advantage of posting text is that one can cut and paste and try exactly what you tried - so thanks for doing that (but note that it was to your advantage to do that: it's unlikely that anybody would type in a program from a screenshot, but if you provide text that can be cut and pasted, it becomes a bit more attractive :-). In any case, I still believe that it's a pandas "feature": see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a pandas "feature" and has nothing to do with Org mode, as pointed out in a comment. The following modification to the code produces untruncated output for me:

```python
#+BEGIN_SRC python
  import pandas as pd
  import statsmodels.api as sm
  import numpy as np

  # tell pandas to not worry about truncation
  pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
  pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
  # and to not worry about the width of the "screen"
  pd.set_option('display.width', None)

  nsample = 50
  sig = 0.25
  X = np.linspace(0, 20, nsample)
  X = sm.add_constant(X)
  beta = [5., 0.5]
  y_true = np.dot(X, beta)
  y = y_true + sig * np.random.normal(size=nsample)

  olsmod = sm.OLS(y, X)
  olsres = olsmod.fit()

  pred = olsres.get_prediction([1,17])

  return(pred.summary_frame())
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: mean   mean_se  mean_ci_lower  mean_ci_upper  obs_ci_lower  obs_ci_upper
: 0  13.406873  0.049386      13.307576       13.50617     12.944031     13.869715
```

The alignment however is bad: org-babel takes the result, stringifies it and writes it to a temporary file. Since it's just a string, it just gets printed out.

EDIT: I can get good alignment too with a `:results drawer` header:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results drawer
 ... no changes to the program ...
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:results:
        mean   mean_se  mean_ci_lower  mean_ci_upper  obs_ci_lower  obs_ci_upper
0  13.439094  0.049308      13.339955      13.538234     12.976986     13.901202
:end:
```

Comment: You are so right! I'd tried the first ` pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)', (and forgot to mention that in my update) but I guess more was needed. Should I delete this question since it's not about emacs, after all?

Comment: It's probably useful even if not emacs-related.  If people feel strongly about it, they can vote to close the question and/or the moderator can decide to delete it.

Comment: Thanks so much, @NickD. FYI, I'm actually outputting pandas dataframes as org tables using the `pd2org` function defined [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html). It's really nice. I wouldn't have asked this question had I known the pred.summary_frame() is a pandas dataframe. (I thought I'd checked it's type, but I guess not.) Learned something useful anyway!